# why are these spans not getting treated as nodes by domdocument()?

Tags: php, domdocument

the result of the following domdocument() call

```php
$html = <<<EOT
```

```
<div class="list_item"> 
         <div class="list_item_content"> 

            <div class="list_item_title"> 
               <a href="/link/goes/here"> 
                  INFO<br /> 
                  <span class="part2">More Info</span><br /> 
                  <span class="part3">Etc.</span> 
               </a> 
            </div> 

      </div>
```

```php
EOT;

libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$titles_nodeList = $xpath->query('//div[@class="list_item"]/div[@class="list_item_content"]/div[@class="list_item_title"]/a');

foreach ($titles_nodeList as $title) {
    $titles[] = $title->nodeValue;
}

echo("<pre>");
print_r($titles);
echo("</pre>");


?>
```

is

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  
                  INFOMore InfoEtc. 

)
```

Why are data in these two spans inside the a element included in the result, when I am not specifying these spans in the path? I am interested only in retrieving data contained in the a element directly, not information contained in the spans inside the a element. I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: SO really did a bad job at syntax highlighting there.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, the syntax highlighter always chokes on HEREDOC strings in PHP.

Comment: @Michael Modified it to at least highlight correctly (can't really fix the white though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
//div[@class="list_item"]/div[@class="list_item_content"]/div[@class="list_item_title"]/a/child::text()
```

Comment: cool, that gives me `Array
(
    [0] =>  
                  INFO
    [1] =>  
               
)` and when I modify it to `//div[@class="list_item"]/div[@class="list_item_content"]/div[@class="list_item_title"]/a/child::text()[1]` I get `Array
(
    [0] =>  
                  INFO
)`. I get the same result if I omit child:: and use `//div[@class="list_item"]/div[@class="list_item_content"]/div[@class="list_item_title"]/a/text()[1]` so I'm a bit confused what the difference is between using and not using child.

Comment: I think `text()` is just an [abbreviation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) for `child::text()`

Answer (score 1):

The nodes are there, but are viewing them in HTML mode in a browser. Try viewing the page source, and/or doing:

```
echo("<pre>");
htmlspecialchars(print_r($titles), true);
echo("</pre>");
```

instead, which'll encode the `<>` into `&lt;&gt;` and make them "visible".

Comment: I looked at the source, but it's just `<pre>Array
(
    [0] =>  
                  INFOMore InfoEtc. 
               
)
</pre>` and using your replacement with htmlspecialchars() I get `Array
(
    [0] =>  
                  INFOMore InfoEtc. 
               
)`. It doesn't seem the spans are showing up, although I don't know why.

Comment: Odd. what version of PHP is this? on 5.x, nodeValue is the undocumented .innerHTML equivalent. You're getting what looks to be .innerTEXT